# I want this action to respond to vcs mime type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app with the following mime type configured in config/ini/mime_types...

```
Mime::Type.register "application/hbs-vcs, text/calendar, text/x-vcalendar", :vcs
```

I have this action in my application_controller...

```
  def do_410
    render :template => "/shared/410", :status => 410
  end
```

I would like this action to respond the vcs extension is it is called. So something like `dev/events/2158.vcs` would respond to this action without an error. Right now I get the error...

```
Missing template shared/410 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:vcs], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
```

I tried a respond_to block in this action but I get the multiple redirect error if I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two steps you need to take in order to enable a custom mime type.
I know you've already done the first one, but I'm adding it here for completeness.

a) Register this mime type to Rails

```
#config/initializers/mime_types.rb
Mime::Type.register "application/hbs-vcs, text/calendar, text/x-vcalendar", :vcs
```

b) In your controller action, specify the format

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :template => "/shared/410", :status => 410 }
end
```

Because your "/shared/410" template does not have an extension, the mime type cannot be recognized. This is why you need to specify it manually.

Comment: I have tried this and I get the error above. I am wondering if its a path issue. Almost like it can't find 410.html.erb

Comment: 410.html.erb? but it should be named 410.vcs. This is why you have added the custom mimetype and use that format.

Comment: Btw, the default folder for shared views is "app/application". Rails knows how to automatically pick the files from there, so you don't have to specify the full path, just the view name.

Comment: That is the goal. For this particular action, rather than respond in the normal way to the .vcs extension, I want to simply render this 410 error message (render html file)

Comment: Then why don't you just do `head :gone` ?

Comment: I edited your answer and accepted. The 410 template does not display with the .vcs extension, but at least an exception is not thrown, which is fine. Status 406 is returned.